# swift syntax, an extra word before the var

Tags: ios, swift

Pardon me for beginner's question

In Swift function, what is the `cellForRowAt`, looks like not a variable (`indexPath` is), nor a type (`IndexPath` is).

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a loot at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html . The developer that uses the function will see `cellForRowAt` if you have specified such parameter and not `indexPath`. So you have the chance to be more descriptive with it.

```
func increment(by amount: Int) {
   //body of the method
}
```

And you use it like that:

```
counter.increment(by: 5)
```